# Preventing certain WAKELOCKS (NlpCollectorWakeLock, NlpWakeLock) with shell? (e.g. pm command)

Tags: shell, services, wakelock

As some of you might aware of, the notorious 'NlpCollectorWakeLock' and 'NlpWakeLock' are often the cause of considerable battery drain. I personally make some custom ROMs, and would like to automatically disable these without any app, but by a simple shell script. I tried disabling some activities by `pm` command, but no luck so far.

So can anyone give me some insight in disabling components/services/activities etc, that is related to these two wakelocks?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if you're in the right tracks with your attempt. Apps aquire wakelocks for a reason (well, at least that's the idea behind). Trouble is not them *aquiring* them, but those wakelocks sometimes *not being released* – which you cannot overcome by that. Your outcome would more likely be several apps/services stopping to work correctly, acting erraneously, or causing other errors.

Comment: If you're rooted, there's an Xposed module that you can use to throttle wakelocks: http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ryansteckler.nlpunbounce